# Photoshop CC 2021 typing backwards (!!!like this)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typesetting

I work as a typesetter in a scanlation team therefore i work with text in photoshop A LOT. Recently, i had to reinstall PS due to resetting Windows. I got the same version i used before (and had no problems with!), and i stumbled upon this issue. Whenever i add a text layer (pasting it using typertools), punctuation symbols are getting typed RTL, whereas i need them to be LTR. (i need it to be "like this!" not "!like this". I already tried switching to middle eastern features, and it gave me a text orientation switch, but it only works for one text layer, layers added later still getting typed RTL. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuEcU.gif

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Tech support is generally off topic here. Sorry about that. Probably best to contact Adobe for support.

Comment: sorry, i just had zero help from them.

Comment: Could be a plug in issue....

Comment: Tech support questions are difficult to resolve without access to your computer/set up, using trial and error, or guessing etc. That's why they are generally off-topic.